# gradle tests hang for spring security tests with embedded ldap server

Tags: spring-security, ldap, gradle

I have a set of tests for spring-security 3.1.3 with embedded ldap server that runs properly from eclipse or when run through gradle with -Dtest.single option. However when i do a clean build to run the entire set of tests in the project the execution hangs at the point where it hits those tests, at which point i have to kill the gradle process. If I @Ignore the ldap tests other tests work fine. These tests work properly if i dont use embedded server i.e connect to an external server. Probably something to do with fact that gradle executes tests in multi-threaded way and it tries to host an in-memory server and all that. 
  Any body faced similar issues ? and how might i get more useful info on what might be going on ? --info or --debug on gradle doesn't help and the test reports (like the ones generated in case of a normal test failure ) are also not generated in case of killing the gradle process .

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set `maxParallelForks` to 1.

Why don't you copy the approach used by Spring Security itself, which configures a [separate task for integration tests](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/gradle/javaprojects.gradle#L68)? It [sets `maxParallelForks` to 1](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/ldap/ldap.gradle#L35) for those tests.

That way you can continue to benefit from running unit tests in parallel.

Comment: maxParallelForks value by default is 1 and i didn't override that value, the issue however seems to be that the test thread didnt have enuf memory , setting "jvmArgs"  on test tasks helped in this case.